# Check my answer: Shortest sequence from $1$ to $2^{2018}$, where each step either doubles or squares the previous value.

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, contest-math

My [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3042072/if-the-number-1-is-written-at-the-beginning-at-least-how-many-steps-should) was about the meaning of the problem. But now, I present a solution. Can MSE verify my answer?

> Given a number, you can perform two operations on it: double it or turn it into its square. Your initial number is one. How many operations at least do you need to turn it into $2^{2018}?$

Is my solution correct?

> $$\begin{align}2^{2018}\longrightarrow 2^{1009}\longrightarrow 2^{1008}\longrightarrow 2^{504}\longrightarrow 2^{252}\longrightarrow 2^{126}\longrightarrow 2^{63}\longrightarrow 2^{62}\longrightarrow 2^{31}\longrightarrow 2^{30}\longrightarrow 2^{15}\longrightarrow 2^{14}\longrightarrow 2^{7}\longrightarrow 2^{6}\longrightarrow 2^{3}\longrightarrow 2^{2}\longrightarrow 2^{1}\longrightarrow 1\end{align}$$

I find answer is $17$. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, that should be correct: you squared it whenever you could, and had you used squaring at the places where you doubled, you would have needed a lot more doubling after that. But a nice clean and hard proof of this would be preferred.